# Jenkins pipeline pass upstream build number to downstream job using Pipeline script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

How to pass upstream build number to downstream job in Pipeline job using (Trigger parameter build on other projects) ?

Agenda: To pass upstream job build number to downstream job to download upstream artefacts in downstream, here's my Jenkins pipeline script

Upstream job script:

```
node 
{
    stage('Build parameters')
    {
    properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: '***', description: '', name: 'version', trim: false)])])
    }/*
    echo env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def Latest_Build_Number=env.BUILD_NUMBER
    build job: 'Downstream', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Latest_Build_Number', value: 'env.BUILD_NUMBER', propagate:false]]    
}

**Downstream job script**:
node 
{
    stage('Downstream')
    {
    properties([[$class: 'ScannerJobProperty', doNotScan: false], parameters([string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'Latest_Build_Number', trim: false)])])
echo Latest_Build_Number
}
}

Error: 
*[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class hudson.model.JobProperty is named ScannerJobProperty
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:478)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:402)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerceList(DescribableModel.java:514)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:388)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:341)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:264)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:178)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `env.BUILD_NUMBER`.

Instead of:

```
value: 'env.BUILD_NUMBER'
```

Try:

```
value: env.BUILD_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a plugin. Remove the `[$class: 'ScannerJobProperty', doNotScan: false]` portion. This works:

*Upstream Job*

```
node {
    stage('Build parameters') {
        properties(
            [parameters(
                [string(
                    defaultValue: '***', 
                    description: '', 
                    name: 'version', 
                    trim: false)
                ])
            ])
    }
    echo env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def Latest_Build_Number = env.BUILD_NUMBER
    build(
        job: 'Downstream', 
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', 
             name: 'Latest_Build_Number', 
             value: env.BUILD_NUMBER, 
             propagate: false]
        ]
    )
}
```

*Downstream Job*

```
node {
    stage('Downstream') {
        properties([
            parameters([string(
                defaultValue: '', 
                description: '', 
                name: 'Latest_Build_Number', 
                trim: false)
            ])
        ])
        echo Latest_Build_Number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Build Failure Analyzer** is the missing plugin name for this.